# Hash function to map consecutive integers to non-distinct integers

Tags: hash, embedded, lookup-tables

I have a sequence of 1760 integers, ranging from 129 to 250, and there is no discernible pattern to these integers. I'm working on a very small embedded system, and can't afford to waste almost 2 KB on a lookup table. I'd like to come up with a function that allows me to lookup a value given an index (in the 0 to 1759 range).

I know that [minimal perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hash_function) would allow me to map distinct values onto a set of consecutive integers, but I'm looking to map a set of consecutive integers onto non-distinct values.

Is brute force over millions of years the only way to do this? Is there some approach that would allow for a much smaller lookup table (say, around 256 bytes or less)?

Comment: What's the input data structure? Presumably these values get stored somewhere? Why isn't that an array which gives you what you need?

Comment: The array is on paper. I'm trying to store it within a program in an efficient manner (i.e. I'm trying to compress it).

Comment: If you want to compress this for a smaller ROM usage in the end, you also have to take in account the code it requires to decode. For example V1bri's suggestion to use 7 bit encoding would save you 220 bytes on the table. You are only better off if the decoding code is less than 220 bytes (which might be tight fit on an AVR for example, possibly requiring doing it in assembler). You might well end up with that whatever you do, the best overall result is just having the simple straightforward 1760 byte table.

Comment: In this case, these tables are being stored in flash, separate from the code. But yes, that's a very good point to consider in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What process generates your 1760 integers? Unfortunately, without knowing a little more about the source of your data it will be difficult (as you say, "millions of years") to find such a function, if it exists. Claude Shannon proved that random noise is at maximum information entropy and therefore impossible to compress. So if there is no discernible pattern to your integers, that indeed qualifies as random noise.

---

Going back to the lookup table, you can reduce the size of your table by 1/8 by recognizing that your integers are all within the range 129-250 which only requires 7 bits to represent. With some bit manipulation tricks in the table lookup you will only require 1760 * 7/8 = 1540 bytes or a 12.5% savings. It's not a lot but it's a start; here's some sample code to illustrate what I mean.

### Sample code

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void compress(const std::vector<uint8_t>& raw, std::vector<uint8_t>& comp) {
    // Length must be a multiple of 8 to handle unrolled loop.
    assert(raw.size() % 8 == 0);

    comp.resize(raw.size() * 7 / 8);
    for (size_t rIdx = 0, cIdx = 0; rIdx < raw.size(); rIdx += 8, cIdx += 7) {
        comp[cIdx + 0] = (raw[rIdx + 0] << 1) | ((raw[rIdx + 1] & 0x7f) >> 6);
        comp[cIdx + 1] = (raw[rIdx + 1] << 2) | ((raw[rIdx + 2] & 0x7f) >> 5);
        comp[cIdx + 2] = (raw[rIdx + 2] << 3) | ((raw[rIdx + 3] & 0x7f) >> 4);
        comp[cIdx + 3] = (raw[rIdx + 3] << 4) | ((raw[rIdx + 4] & 0x7f) >> 3);
        comp[cIdx + 4] = (raw[rIdx + 4] << 5) | ((raw[rIdx + 5] & 0x7f) >> 2);
        comp[cIdx + 5] = (raw[rIdx + 5] << 6) | ((raw[rIdx + 6] & 0x7f) >> 1);
        comp[cIdx + 6] = (raw[rIdx + 6] << 7) | ((raw[rIdx + 7] & 0x7f) >> 0);
    }
}

uint8_t lookup(const std::vector<uint8_t>& comp, size_t rIdx) {
    size_t cIdx = rIdx / 8 * 7;
    switch (rIdx % 8) {
    case 0:
        return                                  (comp[cIdx + 0] >> 1) | 0x80;
    case 1:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 0] & 0x01) << 6) | (comp[cIdx + 1] >> 2) | 0x80;
    case 2:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 1] & 0x03) << 5) | (comp[cIdx + 2] >> 3) | 0x80;
    case 3:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 2] & 0x07) << 4) | (comp[cIdx + 3] >> 4) | 0x80;
    case 4:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 3] & 0x0f) << 3) | (comp[cIdx + 4] >> 5) | 0x80;
    case 5:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 4] & 0x1f) << 2) | (comp[cIdx + 5] >> 6) | 0x80;
    case 6:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 5] & 0x3f) << 1) | (comp[cIdx + 6] >> 7) | 0x80;
    case 7:
        return ((comp[cIdx + 6] & 0x7f) << 0) | 0x80;
    }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<uint8_t> raw { 151, 169, 162, 164, 155, 147, 149, 143, };
    std::vector<uint8_t> comp;

    compress(raw, comp);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < raw.size(); ++i) {
        std::cout << i << ": raw " << static_cast<int>(raw[i])
                  << ", lookup " << static_cast<int>(lookup(comp, i))
                  << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

### Output

I'm just printing out the raw and compressed/uncompressed data at each index to verify storage and retrieval.

```
0: raw 151, lookup 151
1: raw 169, lookup 169
2: raw 162, lookup 162
3: raw 164, lookup 164
4: raw 155, lookup 155
5: raw 147, lookup 147
6: raw 149, lookup 149
7: raw 143, lookup 143
```

There's some work to be done if your input data length is no longer a multiple of 8 but this should get you started.

Comment: Assume the data is random noise. I did consider using 7-bit encoding, and as well as some heavier options like Huffman. What I'm really looking for though is a way to search for a magic number solution akin to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_inverse_square_root, but I suppose if there's no pattern to the data, Newton's method can't be used. I'm starting to think that no solution to my problem exists.

Comment: Are you sure it's random noise? Maybe your data can be represented by some function plus an error term (ex: linear, y = mx + b + err(x)). If the error term can be bounded by 6 (or fewer) bits you can save additional space by storing the function parameters (ex: m, b) at full resolution and storing the error term with a 6 (or fewer) bit encoding.

Comment: Yes, it has a bit of a sinusoidal component to it, bit there are so many high frequency harmonics that it may as well be random noise.